# Failed to read artifact descriptor Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I added dependency for `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`. And I get problem: "Failed to read artifact descriptor..."

[image: This is error]

I downloaded jars and added manually in folder where are all dependency and I   added like Referenced Libraries, but didn't help.
Can someone help me?

This is part of pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Downloading the jars and adding manually will not add the dependencies and child dependecies. Also the pom would not have been updated.
Try deleting the following folders

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc 

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
```

from your maven repository(.m2) and refresh the maven project(ALT + F5).

Then u get can get the actual error(if exists) which u can post it here.

Comment: If you are behind proxy, you are gonna face this issue.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher can you explain what do you mean by "if you are behind proxy," , what is the resolution for this?

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to resolve this issue. Just delete the .m2 folder from the users/username/ location and refresh the maven project in your eclipse workspace or delete the project and import again.

Answer (score 0):

Just reload the `pom.xml` file and make sure that the project connected to the Internet.